# Deleting an Asset file

Tags: community, files, contentdocument, asset

I had an image in a rich text field in my Community.  I was able to access the image file on the internet via the image's URL.  I deleted the Asset File.  However, it is still downloading when I access its URL.  I want to get rid of it completely.  What am I missing?

Comment: It could be a caching issue. Try deleting your local cache/temp files and see if it works.

Comment: Do you mean to do it on the server?  I am not sure how.

Comment: I mean local browser cache and temp downloaded files (if in window)

Comment: I just deleted my cookies & cache.  The file is still accessible.  I emptied the recycle bin where I was able to see the file.  Is it possible Salesforce stores the files on a different server & there will be a delay to see the file deleted everywhere.  This is a pretty big deal for us.  The URL I am using that is still finding the file is...
https://domainname/file-asset/filename?v=1

Comment: I just used Data Loader to export the list of asset files.  The file(s) I deleted are not showing in the export.  It is as if I deleted them.  I don't understand why I can still access them via the URLs.

Comment: Ideally once deleted it shouldn’t have been accessible. I will try to replicate and check once I am at my workstation.

Comment: I deleted 18 files several hours ago.  4 of them are no longer available via the URLs.  The other 14 are still accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days this problem resolved itself.  It seems like the asset files were likely cached on multiple Salesforce servers & it took time for everything to sync.  Salesforce technical support couldn't confirm this but had no other explanation.